# User Downloads In Java Spring

Tags: java, javascript, spring, download, hyperlink

I need to make a link in my Java Spring application that will allow the user to download a CSV file . I have the CSV file in my project's root directory and I have an  tag in my view that runs a Javascript function when it's clicked. Is there any way I can use either Javascript or the Java Spring framework to allow the user to download the CSV file? I'm a noob Spring user/developer so any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: Also see http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip94.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the file in your WebContent (or whatever you call the web resources directory) and link it directly. Everything below WebContent (but not in WEB-INF) is accessible in your context root.

So file WebContent/test.csv is accesible with relative url /test.csv.

Comment: Just an FYI: Nothing below the WEB-INF is accessible via browsing.